# Конвертация цветного в чб и наоборот Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Есть 2D игра. Нужно сделать объекты, кроме игрока, в определенный момент черно-белые (все или выборочно), а затем при определенном условии, к примеру набрал 100 монет, сделать цветным. 
Как это реализовать?
Экспериментировал с gameObject.GetComponent().material.color - ерунда какая-то...

Answer (score 2):

`gameObject.GetComponent().material.color` - не в тут сторону смотрите. В вашей ситуации, я бы посмотрел в сторону шейдера или пост эффекта.

Основная идея в том, что есть вам нужно только игрока рисовать не в черно-белых оттенках, то сделайте пост-эффект на камеру, которая будет рисовать все объекты, кроме игрока. А самого игрока можете рисовать другой камерой.

Гляньте, к примеру, [этот туториал](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/08/screen-shaders-and-postprocessing-effects-in-unity3d/) по черно-белому пост-эффекту. В данном решении, есть только 1 спорный момент - пост-эффекты могут быть очень дорогим с точки зрения производительности решением, по этому необходимо экспериментировать и смотреть на производительность. Однако, переход из черно-белого и обратно, будет легко переключить и для этого не понадобится иметь ссылки на все объекты.

Если вы разрабатываете под standalone платформы, то тут проблем не должно быть, но с мобильными платформами такие проблемы возможны.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пытать шейдеры

Comment: @MichaelReed Если ответ оказался вам полезен, отметьте его пожалуйста, как верный

Comment: Неполноценный ответ, данное решение с применением пост эффекта к определенным объектам нужно правильно применять, просто шейдера не достаточно.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker в вопросе идет речь обо всех объектах, кроме игрока - если рисовать его отдельной камерой, все вопросы отпадают и все решается 1 пост-эффектом

Comment: Ну так и добавьте эту информацию в ответ :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker справедливое замечание, дополил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Я бы смотрел в сторону следующего пути:

Создать 2 камеры. Обе смотрят в ту же сторону и имеют одинаковые настройки визуализации.

- На одной камере отмечаешь отображение всех слоев окроме Selected слоя.
- На второй - наоборот. И повесить grayscale скрипт.

Потом нужно рендерить 2 камеры одну над второй. Детали как это сделать я не подскажу, но так сделать полюбому можно.