# Как сделать изображение черно-белым?

Tags: unity3d, цвета

Удивлен, но ответа в интернете я не нашел, возможно плохо искал.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы картинка, которая изначально цветная, была черно-белой, если игрок еще не купил определенный предмет, за который эта картинка отвечает. Я уверен, что есть лучший способ, чем делать черно-белую копию для КАЖДОГО изображения игры, однако не знаю, можно ли программно обесцветить sprite.

Я постарался изучить эту идею. В частности, наткнулся на следующий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893350/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B1-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-unity). Однако там рассматривается обесцвечивание всей сцены за исключением игрока с помощью с пост-эффектов на камере, а мне нужно сделать черно-белыми несколько отдельных объектов с компонентов SpriteRenderer.

Я также посмотрел такую статью (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance) по Relative luminance. Однако не совсем понял, что конкретно нужно сделать, да и вообще не уверен, что это то, что может помочь. Так что, чтобы не было проблемы XY не буду настаивать что это может быть решением.

Я понимаю, что такого рода вопросы не лучшие для данного сайта, однако я изучил некоторые вещи, но не нашел решения. Возможно в Юнити есть какой-то специальный компонент или ассет из AssetStore для подобных задач?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается через шейдеры.

Скачай ассет ShaderGraph. В нем создай шейдер который делает обьект черно-белым. (погугли "shader graph Grayscale" )

А потом просто меняй шейдер, когда необходимо, на обычный.

Или даже сделай переключатель "черно-белое" сразу в шейдере и переключай в игре прямо его не меняя шейдер в принципе.